# Google Line Chart vetikal Line?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I create a vertical Line on Google Line Charts like This:

https://www.google.de/search?q=dax&oq=dax&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l4.2643j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

I mean the Line that follows the Mouse and displays the value on Top.

Comment: check [option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) for `crosshair.orientation`...

Comment: Thank's ...... it works ;)

Can you tell me how to realize the Top Menu where you can  choose the Options?

1 Day, 5 Days, 1 Month etc.

Thanks for your Solution an have a nice Day

Comment: no standard option for the range selection -- build your own buttons, then use [data table method `getFilteredRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getFilteredRows) to filter on the date / x-axis...

Answer (score 0):

use following [option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)...

```
crosshair: {
  orientation: 'vertical'
}
```